# What do I return if the return type of a method is Void? (Not void!)

Tags: java, generics, void

Due to the use of Generics in Java I ended up in having to implement a function having `Void` as return type:

```
public Void doSomething() {
    //...
}
```

and the compiler demands that I return *something*. For now I'm just returning `null`, but I'm wondering if that is good coding practice...

I'm asking about **V**‌oid, not **v**‌oid. The class `Void`, **not** the reserved keyword `void`.

I've also tried `Void.class`, `void`, `Void.TYPE`, `new Void()`, no return at all, but all that doesn't work at all. (For more or less obvious reasons) (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676663/what-do-i-return-if-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-void-not-void/881358#881358) for details)

- So what am I supposed to return if the return type of a function is `Void`?
- What's the general use of the `Void` class?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

> So what am I supposed to return if the return type of a function has to be `Void`?

Use `return null`. `Void` can't be instantiated and is merely a placeholder for the `Class<T>` type of `void`.

> What's the point of `Void`?

As noted above, it's a placeholder. `Void` is what you'll get back if you, for example, use reflection to look at a method with a return type of `void`. (Technically, you'll get back `Class<Void>`.) It has other assorted uses along these lines, like if you want to parameterize a `Callable<T>`.

> Due to the use of generics in Java I ended up in having to implement this function

I'd say that something may be funky with your API if you needed to implement a method with this signature. Consider carefully whether there's a better way to do what you want (perhaps you can provide more details in a different, follow-up question?). I'm a little suspicious, since this only came up "due to the use of generics".

Comment: Having to return Void is not so funky after all. It can simply be mandated by e.g. Callable<T>. Sometimes you just don’t need to return something but can not use e.g. Runnable.

Comment: Void has legitimate uses, as I noted. But he said that "this only came up due to the use of generics". That makes it sound like he did something to a collection that needs to use Void, which I would say is a rather exceptional case.

Comment: With collections it would be very strange, indeed.

Comment: Both Void.class and void.class are Class<Void> but they are not equal. Void is often used as a generic argument in value of Map (or use the Collections.newSetFromMap) and return of AccessController.doPrivileged.

Comment: @Tom: Yeppers. That's why I tagged the "(Technically, you'll get back Class<Void>.)" Should I amend that part or do you think it's accurate as is?

Comment: Wouldn't the elegant way be if the compiler allowed you to just do "return;", as with any other method of type void? Is there a reason why you have to return null?

Comment: Well, they're not quite the same thing. "return;" returns nothing at all. However, Class<Void> is still an object, even if it can't be instantiated.

Answer (score 27):

There's no way to instantiate a Void, so the only thing you *can* return is null.

Comment: More accurately, there's no way to instantiate a Void without doing evil things.

Answer (score 21):

`return null` is the way to go.

Answer (score 21):

To make clear why the other suggestions you gave don't work:

`Void.class` and `Void.TYPE` point to the same object and are of type `Class<Void>`, not of `Void`.

That is why you can't return those values. `new Void()` would be of type `Void` but that constructor doesn't exist. In fact, `Void` has no public constructors and so cannot be instantiated: You can never have any object of type `Void` except for the polymorphic `null`.

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Minor correction: `Void.TYPE` does not point to `Void.class`. It points to `void.class`.

Answer (score 1):

If, for obscure reasons, you MUST use this type, then indeed returning null seems to be a sensible option, since I suppose return value will not be used anyway.
The compiler will force you to return something anyway.
And this class doesn't seem to have a public constructor so new Void() is not possible.

Comment: I wont be a MUST; it is just convention.

Answer (score -4):

just like this.

```
public Class TestClass {
    public void testMethod () {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP said `Void`, not `void`. The other answers already seem to cover the subject pretty well.