# On Void return type

Tags: java, void

If one needs return a `Void` type, which Javadoc describes as

> A class that is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a
>   reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

Why does the following still require `null` to be returned?

```
public Void blah() {
    return null; // It seems to always want null
}
```

Comment: Because `Void` is not a keyword, but an `Object`.

Comment: possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676663/what-do-i-return-if-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-void-not-void

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`Void`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) is a class like any other, so a function returning `Void` has to return a reference (such as `null`). In fact, `Void` is `final` and uninstantiable, which means that `null` is the only thing that a function returning `Void` could return.

Of course `public void blah() {...}` (with a lowercase `v`) doesn't have to return anything.

If you're wondering about possible uses for `Void`, see [Uses for the Java Void Reference Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643906/uses-for-the-java-void-reference-type)

Comment: *"Of course `public void blah() {...}` (with a lowercase v) doesn't have to return anything."* Indeed, **must** not.

Answer (score 4):

Void is the object "wrapper" for the `void` type.  A return type of `void` doesn't return a  return value but `Void` does.  You can't use `void` or any primitive type in a generic.

Answer (score 3):

The correct keyword in Java is `void`, not `Void` (notice the use of lowercase at the beginning). `Void` (uppercase) is, according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html):

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

Answer (score 1):

As the doc says it is an *uninstantiable placeholder class*, thus you can't get an instance, but you have to return something since `Void != void`. `Void` actually is a *class* and thus treated like any other class/type which requires an instance or null to be returned.