# How does Java know which overloaded method to call with lambda expressions? (Supplier, Consumer, Callable, ...)

Tags: java, function, lambda, overloading

First off, I have no idea how to decently phrase the question, so this is up for suggestions.

Lets say we have following overloaded methods:

```java
void execute(Callable<Void> callable) {
    try {
        callable.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

<T> T execute(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    return supplier.get();
}

void execute(Runnable runnable) {
    runnable.run();
}
```

Going off from this table, I got from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62434813/3845362)

```
Supplier       ()    -> x
Consumer       x     -> ()
BiConsumer     x, y  -> ()
Callable       ()    -> x throws ex
Runnable       ()    -> ()
Function       x     -> y
BiFunction     x,y   -> z
Predicate      x     -> boolean
UnaryOperator  x1    -> x2
BinaryOperator x1,x2 -> x3
```

These are the results I get locally:

```java
// Runnable -> expected as this is a plain void  
execute(() -> System.out.println()); 

// Callable -> why is it not a Supplier? It does not throw any exceptions..
execute(() -> null);

// Supplier -> this returns an Object, but how is that different from returning null?
execute(() -> new Object());

// Callable -> because it can throw an exception, right?
execute(() -> {throw new Exception();});
```

How does the compiler know which method to call?
How does it for example make the distinction between what's a `Callable` and what's a `Runnable`?

Comment: This probably covered somewhere in the Java Language Specification, but especially about this type of things, I find it very hard to read.

Comment: I *imagine* that `Callable<Void>`  is preferred over `Supplier<T>` because it is more specific (similar to `test(Integer i)` being called instead of `test(Object o)` if the parameter is an integer)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe I have found where this is described in official documentation, although a bit hard to read.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3) is mentioned:

> 15.27.3. Type of a Lambda Expression
>
> Note that while boxing is not allowed in a strict invocation context,
> boxing of lambda result expressions is always allowed - that is, the
> result expression appears in an assignment context, regardless of the
> context enclosing the lambda expression. However, **if an explicitly
> typed lambda expression is an argument to an overloaded method, a
> method signature that avoids boxing or unboxing the lambda result is
> preferred by the most specific check (§15.12.2.5).**

and then [here (15.12.2.5)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) is described analytically how the most specific method is chosen.

So according to this for example as described

> One applicable method m1 is more specific than another applicable
> method m2, for an invocation with argument expressions e1, ..., ek, if
> any of the following are true:
>
> m2 is generic, and m1 is inferred to be more specific than m2 for
> argument expressions e1, ..., ek

So

```
// Callable -> why is it not a Supplier?
execute(() -> null);   <-- Callable shall be picked from 2 options as M2 is generic and M1 is inferred to be more specific

void execute(Callable<Void> callable) {  // <------ M1 
   try {
    callable.call();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}


 <T> T execute(Supplier<T> supplier) {  // <------ M2 is Generic
    return supplier.get();
 }
```

Why M1 is inferred to be more specific can be traced down from this process described [here (18.5.4 More Specific Method Inference)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.4)

Comment: Accepting this as _the_ answer, only for it being quite compact to find the answer more quickly. But kudos to @Sweeper for explaining the answer in more detail, without having to sift through the documentation myself!

Answer (score 7):

```
// Callable -> why is it not a Supplier? It does not throw any exceptions..
execute(() -> null);
```

This is because both the `Callable<Void>` method and the `Supplier<T>` method are [applicable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2), but the former is [*more specific*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5). You can see that this is the case by having only one of the two methods, and `execute(() -> null);` will call that method.

To show that `execute(Callable<Void>)` is more specific than `execute(Supplier<T>)`, we'll have to go to [§18.5.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.4), since the latter is a generic method.

> Let m1 be the first method and m2 be the second method. Where m2 has type parameters P1, ..., Pp, let α1, ..., αp be inference variables, and let θ be the substitution [P1:=α1, ..., Pp:=αp].
>
> Let e1, ..., ek be the argument expressions of the corresponding invocation. Then:
>
> - If m1 and m2 are applicable by strict or loose invocation (§15.12.2.2, §15.12.2.3), then let S1, ..., Sk be the formal parameter types of m1, and let T1, ..., Tk be the result of θ applied to the formal parameter types of m2.
> - [...]

So `m1` is `execute(Callable<Void>)`, and `m2` is `execute(Supplier<T>)`. `P1` is `T`. For the invocation `execute(() -> null);`, `e1` is `() -> null`, and `T` is inferred to be `Object`, so `α1` is `Object`. `T1` is then `Supplier<Object>`. `S1` is `Callable<Void>`.

Now quoting only the parts relevant to the question:

> The process to determine if m1 is more specific than m2 is as follows:
>
> - First, an initial bound set, B, is constructed from the declared bounds of P1, ..., Pp, as specified in §18.1.3.
> - Second, for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ k), a set of constraint formulas or bounds is generated.
>
>   Otherwise, Ti is a parameterization of a functional interface, I. It must be determined whether Si satisfies the following five conditions:
>
>   [...]
>
>   If all five conditions are true, then the following constraint formulas or bounds are generated (where U1 ... Uk and R1 are the parameter types and return type of the function type of the capture of Si, and V1 ... Vk and R2 are the parameter types and return type of the function type of Ti):
>
>   - If ei is an explicitly typed lambda expression:
>
>     - [...]
>     - Otherwise, ‹R1 <: R2›.

Note that a lambda with no parameters is an explicitly typed lambda.

Applying this back to your question, `R1` is `Void`, `R2` is `Object`, and the constraint `‹R1 <: R2›` says that `Void` (not the lowercase `void`) is a subtype of `Object`, which is correct and is not contradictory.

Finally:

> Fourth, the generated bounds and constraint formulas are reduced and incorporated with B to produce a bound set B'.
>
> If B' does not contain the bound false, and resolution of all the inference variables in B' succeeds, then m1 is more specific than m2.

Since the constraint `‹Void <: Object›` is not contradictory, there is no `false` constraint, and so `execute(Callable<Void>)` is more specific than `execute(Supplier<T>)`.

---

```
// Supplier -> this returns an Object, but how is that different from returning null?
execute(() -> new Object());
```

In this case, only the `Supplier<T>` method is *applicable*. `Callable<Void>` expects you to return something compatible with `Void`, not `Object`.

---

```
// Callable -> because it can throw an exception, right?
execute(() -> {throw new Exception();});
```

Not *quite*. Throwing an exception made the `Callable<Void>` overload applicable, but the `Runnable` overload is still applicable too. The reason why the former is chosen is still because `Callable<Void>` is more specific than `Runnable` for the expression `() -> { throw new Exception(); }` (relevant parts only):

> A functional interface type S is more specific than a functional interface type T for an expression e if T is not a subtype of S and one of the following is true (where U1 ... Uk and R1 are the parameter types and return type of the function type of the capture of S, and V1 ... Vk and R2 are the parameter types and return type of the function type of T):
>
> - If e is an explicitly typed lambda expression (§15.27.1), then one of the following is true:
>
>   - R2 is `void`.

Basically, any non-`void`-returning functional interface type is more specific than a `void`-returning functional interface type, for explicitly typed lambdas.

Answer (score 4):

It all makes sense and has a simple pattern besides `() -> null` being a `Callable` I think. The `Runnable` is clearly different from the `Supplier`/`Callable` as it has no input and output values. The difference between `Callable` and `Supplier` is that with the `Callable` you have to handle exceptions.

The reason that `() -> null` is a Callable without an exception is the return type of your definition `Callable<Void>`. It requires you to return the reference to some object. The only [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8806783/7947994) reference to return for `Void` is `null`. This means that the lambda `() -> null` is exactly what your definition demands. It would also work for your `Supplier` example if you would remove the `Callable` definition. However, it uses `Callable<Void>` over `Supplier<T>` as the `Callable` has the exact type.

`Callable` is chosen over `Supplier` as it is more specific (as a comment already suggested). The [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) state that it chooses the most specific type if possible:

> Type inference is a Java compiler's ability to look at each method invocation and corresponding declaration to determine the type argument (or arguments) that make the invocation applicable. The inference algorithm determines the types of the arguments and, if available, the type that the result is being assigned, or returned. Finally, the inference algorithm tries to find the most specific type that works with all of the arguments.

Comment: What if I want to pass a 'void' that can potentially throw an exception, will it use `Runnable` or `Callable`?
`execute(() -> someVoidThatCouldThrowAnError());`

Comment: Runnables can also throw exceptions. If the return type is `void` and there are no arguments it will always be a `Runnable`. The advantage of the `Callable` is that you know that an `Exception` can occur and therefore can handle it appropriately.

Comment: So the compact table should actually be `Runnable () -> () throws ex`? And then the difference between Callable and Runnable is void vs returntype, right?

Comment: Not really, also a `Supplier` can throw an `Exception`, which you can catch. So, it is always possible that some Exception is thrown. With the `Callable` you **must** catch the Exception and handle it. This has the advantage that you cannot miss any Exception that you aren't aware of for example.