# Java help:How do I fix this error?

Tags: java

In my class we are working on a java program that creates 'cards' with a face value and suit. It uses two files, one being a runner and one being the class.However I have been stumped by a series of errors in my code that I can't figure out how to get rid of.

This is my code for the card class:

```
public class Card
{
    public static final String FACES[] = {"ZERO","ACE","TWO","THREE","FOUR",
            "FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE","TEN","JACK","QUEEN","KING"};

        private String suit;
        private int face;

        public Card()
        {
            face = 0;
            suit = "CLUBS";
        }
        //set methods
        public Card(String str1, int int1)
        {
            face = int1;
            suit = str1;
        }

    public int getFace()
    {
        return face;
    }

    public String getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }
    public Void setFace(int face)
    {
        face = face;
        return face;
    }
    public Void setSuit(String suit)
    {
        suit = suit;
        return suit;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return FACES[face] + " of " + suit;
    }
 }
```

The part That is giving me issues is setSuit() and setFace().

before this I tries This.suit or This.face and that gave me a return error asking me to return (which of course didn't work)

this current setup gives me an error saying that it cannot convert to void.

I feel like this is so simple, yet I'm a novice and just started trying java about three weeks ago, so can someone help me out here? I don't just want an answer, I want to understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Look into what the return type of void means.

Comment: @DjBarrington here is a tip for you, if you are using an IDE like _Eclipse_ then setters/getters can be generated for you. Click on **Source** on the menu bar followed by **Generate Getters and Setters**

Comment: I think you are mistaking [Void](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676663/what-do-i-return-if-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-void-not-void) and the return type I think you wanted which is with a lower case v, `void`)

Answer (score 3):

Ok there are two issues here :
1- First issue isn't necessarily a wrong thing but it isn't really needed here. You made your method return Void which would be needed in class that  only allows methods that return Objects only or any other similar scenario. While here a void would really suffice.

2- void means nothing . So if your return type is void you shouldn't return anything , infact it wouldn't make sense to call a method setSuit and then ask it to return a value it is like telling your friend to put the food in the fridge and wait for him to give you the food.Now if you used the "Void" which I advised against you would have to return null since Void is an Object so it's something to be returned . Since Void also means nothing it wouldn't make sense for it to be instantialbe (i.e: You cant' make this:

```
Void nothing=new Void();
```

Thus in this case you will have to return null(which means nothing). Now if the last part didn't make sense it's alright just put void as a return type and you wouldn't have to return anything.

Lastly you have to put this that you said you put since the "this" will make java realize which face/suit you are referring to , thus assigning the  setFace/SetSuits's method face parameter to the object's face parameter (this).

Here is a modified version of your methods:

```
 public void setFace(int face){
    this.face = face;
}

public void setSuit(String suit){
   this.suit = suit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the method is void and you are returning values, if it's void you shouldn't return value to those two methods, or edit them to their return types
Simply try deleting the return statements setters actually don't return they just set that's unnecessary since you have getter

Answer (score 1):

As said by user6798995 the issue is below code

```
public Void setFace(int face)
    {
        face = face;
        return face;
    }
    public Void setSuit(String suit)
    {
        suit = suit;
        return suit;
    }
```

you cannot return something if the return type is void

So these should be

```
    public void setFace(int face)
    {
        face = face;
    }
    public void setSuit(String suit)
    {
       this.suit = suit;

    }
```

For main method you can do

```
Card c=new Card();
c.setFace(7);
c.setSuit("Clubs");

System.out.prinln("Face is"+c.getFace +" Suit is"+ c.getSuit());
```

Answer (score 1):

well, if anyone comes across this, I learned the hard way, but void needs to be used. "Void" is an object, which is what was giving me problems.